# Weird Nebensatz

Tags: subordinate-clause

> Die Bewohner in der WG führen sicher kein Leben im finanziellen Überfluss, aber mit dem Luxus, überall mitentscheiden und mitgestalten zu können; **ein Prinzip, das allen wichtig ist, in der realen Umsetzung erfolgreich alle Mitglieder versorgt und sich finanziell rechnet.**

I'm really confused by the sentence in bold. Literal translation to English would help. The first part of the sentence is quite clear:

> Ein Prinzip, das allen wichtig ist: a principle that is important to everyone.

But the second part is really weird:

> in der realen Umsetzung erfolgreich alle Mitglieder versorgt und sich finanziell rechnet.

Where is the subject? I think the first half of it is missing "werden" as in the passive voice:

> In der realen Umsetzung werden erfolgreich alle Mitglieder versorgt.

But the second half "sich finanziell rechnet" is confusing. Please explain to me how these sentences are built.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ein Prinzip" belongs to all three clauses. You can see this sentence as a list of clauses:

> Ein Prinzip, das allen wichtig ist.

> Ein Prinzip, das in der realen Umsetzung erfolgreich alle Mitglieder versorgt.

> Ein Prinzip, das sich finanziell rechnet.

As you might notice, these clauses are incomplete. You could add something like "das ist" to each, making them "das ist ein Prinzip, das ...".

So a translation might be something like

> (This is) a principle, that is important to everybody, that successfully sustains all members if implemented in reality and that pays off financially.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know you could do this. Thank you.